# react native: Add an icon to the right of the selected record (selected)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In the function in my example then when I mark an entry then it is grayed out (selected), I want to add a "check" icon next to each selected entry.
I would love some help on my issue.

```
function selectItem(data) {
    data.item.isSelect = !data.item.isSelect;
    data.item.selectedClass = data.item.isSelect
      ? styles.selected
      : styles.list;
    const newDataSource = dataSource.map((item) => {
      if (item.zoneId === data.item.zoneId) {
        item = data.item;
      }
      return item;
    });

    setDataSource(newDataSource);
  }
```

Comment: Hello - I think your question could be improved by sharing the parts of your code that interact with your `selectItem` function so that we can try to see the full picture. In particular, I'm curious to see your JSX for an "entry". Perhaps you could conditionally render your check icon component in front of your entry component when its `isSelect` prop is `true`. I'm not sure without seeing more code.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Share some more code